# How to upload an Outlook file ( .msg extension) using the Paperclip gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, outlook, paperclip-validation

I need to be able to attach emails to a model, specifcally .eml and .msg files

Paperclip now requires validations of the types of files upload with it.

The section of my code where those validations live is here:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :supporting_document,
:content_type => ['application/pdf', 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                  'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png',
                  'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12', 'application/msword',
                  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',EML_MIMETYPE],
:message => 'incorrect file type.'
```

That last part, EML_MIMETYPE, is for .eml files, and is defined as a constant:

`EML_MIMETYPE = 'message/rfc822'`

I found the proper MIME TYPE for .eml files by using the file command in the terminal on a test .eml file:

`$ file -b --mime-type ~/Desktop/noname.eml`

However, when I do this on a sample .msg file, it give me back what looks like a corrupted MIME type

```
$ file -b --mime-type ~/Desktop/testemail.msg
>application/CDFV2-corrupt
```

Looking online, this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8efe300d-c917-4be7-a0f3-e620e029842b/what-mime-type-can-i-use-for-msg-files?forum=netfxnetcom suggested maybe using a MIME type of "application/vnd.ms-outlook" , but I've had no luck.

Any suggestions? I am running linux xubuntu 14.04, and the app is using Rails 3.2.18 and ruby 1.9.3p392

Answer (score 0):

Why not default to application/octet-stream?

Comment: Not sure how I would do that...could you post an example of the code I would use?

Comment: I know next to nothing about Ruby, how do you set the content type now?

Comment: Did you find any solution?